# Iframe is not working after zooming

Tags: html, css, iframe, zooming

I need small help with my Iframe.

I have i frame that works fine.

```
<div id="my-div" style="width:790px; height:240px; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: scroll; position:relative;">
<iframe style="position:absolute; top: -245px; left: -3px; width:1280px; height:490px;"
src="http://www.augustyna.pl/prognozy/17dni.php" id="my-iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

But i had to make my website biger in 1920px and in this situation my i frame looks terrible, can you tell me how i can fix it in this case?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  body {
    zoom:130%;
    }
}
```

this is were the website is: [www.surfszkola.pl/prognoza](http://www.surfszkola.pl/prognoza)
Thank you in advence!

Comment: It seems like the media query you posted never gets loaded, I bet that's where your error is.

Comment: its get loaded in google chrome, where website was too small.. Any idea how i can fix that?

Comment: I assume you want to have the iframe zoomed in when people have a smaller screen? in that case, your query in not loaded, look for yourself: http://i.imgur.com/VScnQXD.jpg - If that's not what you meant, please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please not that `zoom` is not a part of the CSS Specification and has limited support: http://caniuse.com/#search=zoom

Comment: The problem is that my site is to small on chrome, so i deside to use zoom, maybe there is some better way(?) and right now i see because of you that using iframe is not the best idea in this case.. Maybe you have some sugestion what can i use to see this wheater on my website...

Comment: Can you suggest what is the best way to make  weather from Augustyna like this website: http://boardrockerz.pl/Pogoda . Because i have now idea how the did this without iframe...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to display the content you like to different screen sizes:

```css
iframe {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  -ms-zoom: 1.5;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .content_viewport {
    border: 0px none;
    margin-left: -36px;
    height: 812px;
    margin-top: -486px;
    width: 650px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .content_viewport {
    border: 0px none;
    margin-left: -306px;
    height: 812px;
    margin-top: -86px;
    width: 650px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid #D5CC5A; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 575px;">
<iframe src="http://augustyna.pl/prognozy/jastarnia.php" scrolling="no" class="content_viewport">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
```